# Assigning value from JSON attribute to innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i got an `<a>` tag which look like this:

```
<a class="js-swatch-item-link swatch__item-inner-image" data-layer-click="{"event":"interaction","interaction":{"category":"colorPattern","action":"Select","label":"DARK GREY MELANGE","value":"DARK GREY MELANGE"}}}" href="#">DARK GREY MELANGE</a>
```

I am trying to fetch the value of the `interaction` section of the JSON string, and then afterwards assigning this value to the innerHTML of the `<a>` tag.

My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var SWATCH_COLOR_LINK = '.swatch.colorpattern a';
var swatchColorLink = document.querySelectorAll(SWATCH_COLOR_LINK);
var swatchColorTitle = JSON.parse(swatchColorLink.getAttribute('data-layer-click')).interaction.value;

for (var i = 0; i < swatchColorLink.length; i++) {
    swatchColorLink[i].innerHTML = swatchColorTitle;
}
```

The function is giving me the following error: `swatchColorLink.getAttribute is not a function`

However if I try to just select the first element like this: `document.querySelectorAll(SWATCH_COLOR_LINK)[0]`

The function works fine and sets the right value from the JSON string to the innerHTML of the `<a>` tag.

Im guessing im doing something wrong in my loop to go over all `<a>` tags and assigning them the value of their JSON string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: That’s confusing. In the `for` loop, you know that `swatchColorLink` contains a collection of elements, in the `.getAttribute` line, however, you don’t…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is laying in `swatchColorLink.getAttribute()`. Because your `swatchColorLink`'s value is a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is returned from `querySelectorAll()` method. When you are doing `document.querySelectorAll(SWATCH_COLOR_LINK)[0]` you are getting the first element from this `NodeList` so in this case your `swatchColorLink` is the single node.

```
var SWATCH_COLOR_LINK = '.swatch.colorpattern a';
var swatchColorLink = document.querySelectorAll(SWATCH_COLOR_LINK);


for (var i = 0; i < swatchColorLink.length; i++) {
    var swatchColorTitle = JSON.parse(swatchColorLink[i].getAttribute('data-layer-click')).interaction.value;
    swatchColorLink[i].innerHTML = swatchColorTitle;
}
```

Comment: I send you kisses ! Thanks for your answer, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your JSON string `{"event":"interaction","interaction":{"category":"colorPattern","action":"Select","label":"DARK GREY MELANGE","value":"DARK GREY MELANGE"}}}`

you should escape the quotes `"` in the string and remove the last `}`

```
<a class="js-swatch-item-link swatch__item-inner-image" data-layer-click="{\"event\":\"interaction\",\"interaction\":{\"category\":\"colorPattern\",\"action\":\"Select\",\"label\":\"DARK GREY MELANGE\",\"value\":\"DARK GREY MELANGE\"}}"href="#">DARK GREY MELANGE</a>
```